# Using update data from Clipboard

Tags: c#, winforms, clipboard, paste

I try to set a data in a Clipboard. I use `Clipboard.SetFileDropList`.

I see that after the instruction for setting data in Clipboard, the data in Clipboard is available after that thread in which this code run is dead. Why?

I resolve this by creating a new thread..and I waiting that is dead.
Is there a way avoid creating a new thread?

........
This function handler is in a sta thread

```
      private static void handler()
    {
        IPAddress ipAd = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList[1];
        TcpListener server = new TcpListener(ipAd, 8003);
        /* Start Listeneting at the specified port */
        server.Start();
        MessageBox.Show("The server isS running at port 8003...");
        for (; ; )
        {
            s = server.AcceptSocket();

            clipboardhandler(s);  }}


      private static void clipboardhandler()
    { 


   ..............
   ..............
StringCollection scex = new StringCollection();
string[] Listfile = Directory.GetFiles("Extract", "*.*");
string[] Listdir = Directory.GetDirectories("Extract", "*.*");

foreach (string fa in Listfile)
{
    scex.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(fa));
}

foreach (string fb in Listdir)
{
    scex.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(fb));
}

Clipboard.SetFileDropList(scex);
MessageBox.Show("clipboard update!");

if (Clipboard.ContainsFileDropList()) 
{
    MessageBox.Show("clip piena");

    StringCollection at = new StringCollection();
    at=Clipboard.GetFileDropList();

    foreach (String ste in at) 
    {
         MessageBox.Show(ste);
    }
}
```

When clipboardhandler() returns, if I go in a directory and press paste, not works.
But if after returns of function, I close the program (thread dead), it's works

So I resolve creating a new thread that execute clipboardhandler...
Why this happens?
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite understand the problem. Is it that the data in clipboard _remains_ after the thread is terminated, or is it that the data in clipboard gets _lost_ after the thread gets terminated?

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. Could you please read through these [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post your code? That way it's easier for people to help you.

Comment: The data in clipboard are available for paste ( in a directory for example) only after that the thread is dead

Comment: I don't see a new thread in your code. I put your code in a button's Click event handler, it works as expected.